# Sources for auctioning/bidding on Simchas Torah

Tags: sources-mekorot, minhag, simchat-torah

There is a widespread custom to bid for various kibbudim on Simchas Torah e.g. for each of the pesukim starting with אתה הראת לדעת.

The practice is attributed to the Maharil - see the [Sefer Taamei Haminhagim](https://tablet.otzar.org/#/book/650526/p/202/t/16966069312121234/fs/xyX6QMG2wmWmIPSF1jUBjyb46zwCsghlrVLmp4xyoKLL/start/0/end/24/c):

[image]

Does anyone know (including the Maharil - I can't seem to locate it) some sources for the practice and why it is regarded as an "auspicious" minhag?

Comment: Are you saying bidding is auspicious? Like if we already know I'm getting kibbud X and agreed to pay Y, we have to go through the actions of an auction because the action is auspicious?

Comment: No I'm not saying that is necessarily has to go through the medium of an auction but would like to know why it is a mitzvah to purchase these things specifically on Simchas Torah. Someone told me there's more written about it in the Maharik?

Comment: Isn't it about Kavod Hatorah- honoring the torah- an important theme of Simchas Torah?